# unconstrained optimization with Laguerre polynomial

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, polynomials, nonlinear-optimization

I have a matrix X and a distance matrix D={d_ij}.  I have  an optimization problem to be solved. The problem is:
[image]

Theta_i is the unkown vectors and L is the  Laguerre polynomial.
How I can write this objective function in matlab in order to use fminunc.

Thank you